# Highcharts not displaying data but drawing chart when reading from CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I have spent many hours learning JavaScript and HighCharts today.  I am trying to get this chart to display.  I managed to get the JSON to work but I would prefer to get the CSV to work as all of my files are in CSV.  I have gone through the JavaScript debugger a lot and see that my data is saving correctly but yet the data does not draw.  The axis and title do display.  Attached is my code.  Thanks in advance for help.  For whatever reason, the JSFiddle doesn't work so feel free to look at what I mean at: [www.teratuple.com/data/dataVolume.html](http://www.teratuple.com/data/dataVolume.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "container" style = "width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
    var seriesData = [];
    var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                selected: 1 // all
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Volume (mm3)'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume Differential'
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [],
                    tooltip: {
                       pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                       valueDecimals: 2
                   }
                }]
            };
            $.get('www.teratuple.com/data/volumeData.csv', function (data) {
                var lines = data.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');
                    if (lineNo > 0) {
                        seriesData.push([parseInt(items[0]), parseFloat(items[1])]);
                    }    
                });
                options.series.data = seriesData;
                chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `series` property is meant to be an array so set your series data via

```
options.series[0].data = seriesData;
```

Comment: Haha thank you so much! I spent hours upon hours trying to debug this and it's usually something small like this.  Thanks again!

Comment: It now works but it doesn't draw the line! Oh well, one problem down.  Onward to the next one...

Comment: Sorry for the spam.  I figured it out.  The last element that is read in by the CSV is two NaN values.  If I slice these out, it works perfectly.  I need to figure out why the CSV is not reading correctly.

Comment: And done, additional line of white space in the file.  Thanks again Phil! Chart works great!